# Matlab how to select markers on plot that are too small to be clicked on

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to edit a figure by selecting markers to make them bigger. However, the markers are too small and are hidden below a line of best fit. Whenever I try to click on the markers, I select the line instead. How can I select the markers only?

I'm plotting using

```
[fitresult, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft, opts );
h = plot( fitresult, xData, yData );
```

Comment: Alternatively, when you plot them, set them directly at a good size. ex: `hp=plot(x,y,'Markersize',10)`. Increase or decrease the `Markersize` to your needs.

Comment: @Hoki thanks. I would prefer not to have to re-do all the manual edits I did to the plot, though. I'll re-plot if all else fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pop your marker on top with `uistack(marker_obj,'top')`, so that they will be drawn on top of the trend line. Downside is that the trend line will be hidden below the markers.

Alternatively, you can can set your trend line so that it is not clickeable: `set(trendline_obj,'HitTest','off')`. The click will hit the next object below (marker, axes object,...). Downside is that you can't have a callback associated to clicking on the trend line. See HitTest in the documentation of Line properties

The solution to have the line drawn on top and a callback upon clicking on the line, is to make a duplicate of the trend line. Have one copy drawn on top with `HitTest='off'` and another one drawn at the bottom (below the markers) with `HitTest='on'` and a callback. The callback will be called when clicking on portions of the line that are not covered by markers.

Comment: Thanks! What do I need to replace `trendline_obj` with, if I'm using the output of `fit()`? (see updated question)

Comment: Not sure what the `fit()` function does. You can click on the line immediately enter `trendline_obj=gco;` in the command line. `gco` points to the last graphical object selected. You can then check if the properties of `trendline_obj` are consitent with the trend line... If not, retry. I understand better what you are doing and I am not 100% sure that the HitTest property will work when manually editing figures.

Comment: For some reason, that made the markers unclickable as well. But that's probably a weird feature of what `fit()` returns. This is good to know, though, thanks!